# Can I pass through Abu Dhabi airport with phiseptone while traveling to the Philippines?

Tags: health, philippines, abu-dhabi

Can I pass through Abu Dhabi airport with my controlled drug (phiseptone) while traveling to the Philippines? Also can I enter the Philippines with this medication?

Comment: do you mean physeptone aka methadone?

Comment: Similar question, but no answer: https://travel.stackexchange.com/questions/183215/traveling-transiting-uae-with-controlled-medication